# pythonのautopep8でif文のインデントが一定にならない

Tags: python, python3, vscode

Python3のフォーマッターにautopep8を用いています。
下記のようなコードを書いた後、autopep8でフォーマットすると、２つのif文のインデントが一致せず、困っています。
２つのif文のインデントを一致させる方法はありますか？

#### フォーマット前

```
txt = 'a'

if ((txt == 'a')
    or (txt == 'b')
    or (txt == 'b')
    or (txt == 'b')
    or (txt == 'b')
    ):
    print('hoge')

if ((txt == 'a')
            or (txt == 'b')
            or (txt == 'b')
            or (txt == 'b')
            or (txt == 'b')
            ):
    print('hoge')
```

#### フォーマット後

```
txt = 'a'

if ((txt == 'a')
        or (txt == 'b')
        or (txt == 'b')
        or (txt == 'b')
        or (txt == 'b')
        ):
    print('hoge')

if ((txt == 'a')
    or (txt == 'b')
    or (txt == 'b')
    or (txt == 'b')
    or (txt == 'b')
    ):
    print('hoge')
```

#### 動作確認環境

Python 3.8.5
autopep8 1.5.4
Visual Studio Code 1.52.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

私の環境でも再現しました。
`"--select=E101,E122,E123,E124,E126,E127,E128",`を追加したら問題が解消しました。

【settings.json】

```
    "python.formatting.provider": "autopep8",
    "python.formatting.autopep8Args": [
        "--aggressive",
        "--aggressive",
        "--select=E101,E122,E123,E124,E126,E127,E128",
    ],
```

E127,E128あたりで、この問題が解消するようです。
--selectで指定した値は以下を参考にしました。
https://github.com/hhatto/autopep8

> Features
> autopep8 fixes the following issues reported by pycodestyle:

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。私の環境でも問題が解消することを確認できました。--selectオプションは一部の修正のみを適用するオプションだと思っているのですが、なぜ--selectオプションで解消するんでしょうかね？

Comment: githubに下記の記載がありました。デフォルトではE2のみ修正するということみたいですね。  


> By default autopep8 only makes whitespace changes.